# Jenkinsfile Access global variable in when condition

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, global-variables, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to access global variables in the jenkinsfile pipeline in when condition.

I need global variable for some use-case. Hence I have used it.
Example :

```
def client = 'client-1'
def role = 'front'
def env = 'prod'

// Conditionally define a variable 'impact'
if (role == 'front' && env == 'prod') {
  impact = "high"
} else if (role == 'front' && env == 'dev') {
  impact = "low"
} else if (role == 'db' && env == 'stg') {
  impact = "medium"
} else {
  impact = "unknown"
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage ("Impact") {
        when {
               // here access client variable from global... run if its value is client-1
               
            }  
      steps {
        echo "The impact is ${impact}"
        sh "echo ${role}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. We need to use the expression in When condition to access global variables.

```
when {
          expression { client == 'client-1' }
     }
```